# Using double quotes within a string

Tags: ios, xcode

I am constructing database queries that include double quotes (") in Xcode.
For example I have this line of code to generate my query:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = \"%@\"", siteName];
```

where

```
siteName = "TestSite"
```

Everything worked fine in Xcode 5 I would get the correct string:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = "TestSite""
```

After upgrading to Xcode 6, if I run the exact same code then the escape sequence doesn't work and I get:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = \"TestSite\""
```

I have even tried replacing the escape sequence with the the ASCII code for double quotes (34) like so:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = %c%@%c", 34, siteName, 34];
```

and I still get

```
query = "SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = \"TestSite\""
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Is there some obscure setting that is different in Xcode 6?

Comment: Obligatory: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Assuming that you have put in your question is the output from `NSLog` then the '\' isn't actually in the string - it is just how NSLog prints it. Try logging the length of the string...

Comment: What do you mean by "escape sequence doesn't work"?

Comment: Do not build queries with string formats. Properly bind valies to prepared statements.

Comment: I am not using NSLog.  I have set a breakpoint and I am observing the value of query from the debugger.

Comment: @Scott Hunter.   By 'escape sequence doesn't work' I mean that the \" is not being replaced with " in my string.

Comment: @rmaddy.   Not sure what you mean.  Can you give an example?

Comment: Search on sqlite3_prepare_v2 and sqlite3_bind_text.

Comment: `query = "SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = "TestSite""` is clearly bogus & would have never worked.

Comment: (Use single quotes inside a SQL statement, so that you don't have to hassle with escaping double quotes.)

Comment: (Basically, everything you've said in your question is nonsense.  Your failure, if there is one, is almost certainly unrelated to the escaped quotes.)

Comment: *I have set a breakpoint and I am observing the value of query from the debugger.* -- You understand, of course, that the debugger lies.  Never trust what it shows you -- either use NSLog or use `po` in the console log window.

Comment: @hot-licks  The fact remains that `select id from site where name = "TestSite"` has worked in Xcode 5 for over 12 months, but has stopped working in Xcode 6 because the escaped quote is no longer 'escaped'.  Maybe single quotes would have fixed it as you suggested.  I decided to switch to the binding method as mentioned in Doug's answer.  I appreciate the time you spent reading and replying though.  Cheers.

Comment: You are mistaken about the cause of your troubles, but so long as you're happy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = ?"];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
    == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, NULL);
```

This is what @rmaddy is talking about, and it is definitely the way to go. I had no end of troubles trying to do it the way you are until I started binding like this.

Comment: Obviously, you don't need `stringWithFormat` at all here, just `NSString *query = @"SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = ?";`. Or, even simpler, just `const char *query = "SELECT id FROM site WHERE name = ?";` and then `sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, nil);`.

Comment: True, that is code leftover from before changing to binding. It hasn't been cleaned up yet.

Comment: Thanks Doug and @rmaddy.  While I still don't understand why the escape quote \" was working fine in Xcode 5 but now not in Xcode 6, I have at least got my database queries working again using your binding suggestion.  Cheers.